# How to edit a community builder page to add logic

Tags: lightning-community, community-builder

I want to edit the community builder  login page to redirect to another custom page. I can access the community builder page, but there seems to be no way for me to add logic to it. Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible. probably you can enable standard "Login discovery" page which have "handler" class or create brand new Visual force page with controller class to redirect on post login.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar requirement, what I did was to build a lighning component without any markup just an init handler and in the init function I did the redirection, placed the component in the home page at the bottom, the redirection happen once the user is logged (retrieve user logged Id, check for you logic and redirect then if it mets the condition to redirect), not so fancy but worked.